# How do I print multiple images to one page on Chrome OS?

Tags: printing, operating-systems, google-chrome-os, pictures

I cannot seem to figure out how to print multiple pictures per page using Chrome OS. Would appreciate any advice. I'm googling and searching for a Chrome OS app or extension now, but so far no luck.

I can print a picture no problem to my cloud-enabled printer. The problem is I want to print more than 1 picture per page to save paper.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had to do this, and used the following method:

- Assuming the photos are in photos.google.com
- Select the photos you want to print
- Go to the + sign (Add to ...)
- Add to collage - it will create a multi-photo collage that fits on one page (or did in my case - tested it with 5 photos)
- Print it - voila

Comment: Google's collage isn't flexible at all and probably only works for square images. You may need to crop the images to be square beforehand. Otherwise, Google just crops the center of the images. Using Google docs seems easier.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my Googling, there is currently no native support in Chrome OS to print multiple pictures to a single sheet.

The workaround is to open Google Docs, create a new Document and drag all of your pictures into this document. Switch the document to landscape mode and then go to File->'Page Setup' and adjust the margins to ".1". Then go through each picture one by one and adjust the size of the pictures to your liking. This method of printing pictures is a bit cumbersome, but provided the exact functionality I was looking for.

I hope Google (or other contributors) adds an extension or app to accomplish this same thing automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Done from my Chromebook.

Go to Chrome Web Store and find Picture Printer.  Add to Chrome.  A printer icon appears on the bar at top right. Press it.

Get a page of Chrome and a page of Google Photos on your screen side by side.

At present you cannot copy from the Google Photos "Photo" page, you need to click on a photo, then you can drag and drop it onto the Picture Printer page.

When you print you must make sure that headers and footers are off and the resize is set to 100%.

Works a treat with some niggles.